# Edit multiple input with jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, dynamic, textinput

I've got a dynamic multiple text input:

```
<input type="text" id="text_1">
<input type="text" id="text_2">
<input type="text" id="text_3">
<input type="text" id="text_4">
<input type="text" id="text_5"> ....
```

How do I get the id on each textinput with jQuery to edit:

```
$('#form').submit(function(){
  $.post('include/setting.php', {
    text_(id): $('#text_(id)').val(), // <--
  }, 'json')
  return false;
})
```

And with php how do I get the input id?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [serialize()](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/)

```
$('#form').submit(function(){
  $('#form input[id]').each(function(){
   $(this).attr('name', $(this).attr('id'));
  });
  $.post('include/setting.php', $('#form').serialize());
  return false;
})
```

Comment: @Rocket you are right. I changed my answer (now I add name atribute to each input depend of it id).

Comment: You can use `$('#form input[id]')` to get inputs with `id`s, you don't need `[id*=""']`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, to share the information with php, you need to send that ajax data with get or post, which means that in php you'll be accepting the data with `$_REQUEST['url_var_name']` (which accepts either). For example:

```
$requests = array('name', 'time', 'city'); // Request whitelist.
$params = array(); // Empty array to hold the final values.
foreach($requests as $param){
    $params[$param] = @$_REQUEST[$param]; // Null by default.
}
// End up with an array of whitelisted parameters in $params to cast or restrict.
```

Secondly, since you're selecting multiple elements, you might want to either use a class on all the elements and then iterate over them with jQuery `.each()`, or just select for input elements within a certain div, to make things simpler.  For example:

```
<div id='#name-inputs'>
<input type="text" id="text_1">
<input type="text" id="text_2">
<input type="text" id="text_3">
<input type="text" id="text_4">
<input type="text" id="text_5">
</div>
```

Then you would interact with the inputs via `$('#name-inputs input')` instead of pulling them individually by id.  In that way you can really name the inputs whatever you want without limiting them to a numeric looping scheme.

**Edit:** @ARTStudio's suggestion on `serialize()` is probably even better than dealing with the inputs individually in the javascript (new function to me, I like it).

Comment: thanks! and how do i get the value with serialised form in php

Comment: As Rocket mentions, the parameters are going to be named whatever you put as the name attribute in the form.  So `<input type='text' name='city'>` will be the post equivalent of `somepage.php?city=SomeThing` except not in a url and is accessed via `$_REQUEST['city']` in php.  In the case of the php code example that I gave above, you'd just stick `$requests = array('city');` as the starting point to get the chosen options out later.